# Nested pseudo elements ::before & ::after not working with @keyframes animation

Tags: css, animation, sass, pseudo-element

I am trying to apply a cool "Glitch Effect" I saw in this video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HpOi_tSMAoY&t=1s):

However, I cannot seem to get this animation to work. Here is the heading element I am trying to apply the effect to:

```
<h1 class="header-block-heading-primary">Web Developer</h1>
```

Here is the SCSS:

```
.header-block-heading-primary {
  // animation: glitch-effect 3s infinite;
  position: relative;

  &::before,
  &::after  {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;

    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: -1;
  }

  &::before {
    color: red;
    animation: glitch-effect 3s infinite;
  }

  &::after {
    color: blue;
    animation: glitch-effect 2s infinite;
  }
}
```

Here is the animation:

```
@keyframes glitch-effect {
  0% {
    left: -3px;
    top: -3px;
  }

  25% {
    left: 3px;
    top: 0px;
  }

  50% {
    left: -2px;
    top: 3px;
  }

  75% {
    left: 2px;
    top: -2px;
  }

  100% {
    left: 0px;
    top: -3px;
  }
}
```

And here is the outputted CSS:

```
.header-block-heading-primary {
  position: relative;
}

.header-block-heading-primary::before,
.header-block-heading-primary::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.header-block-heading-primary::before {
  color: red;
  -webkit-animation: glitch-effect 3s infinite;
  animation: glitch-effect 3s infinite;
}

.header-block-heading-primary::after {
  color: blue;
  -webkit-animation: glitch-effect 2s infinite;
  animation: glitch-effect 2s infinite;
}
```

I have followed the same setup as the tutorial, and even referenced some old projects of mine looking at the use of `::before` and `::after` and they work just fine with the practically the same code (for the pseudo elements).

I have tried just single semi-colon, so `:before` & `:after`, and that did not work. I added the animation directly to the element itself (as seen by the commented out `// animation: glitch-effect 3s infinite;` underneath the `.header-block-heading-primary` selector), and it works fine so I'm being led to believe the `::before` and `::after` elements are not working. Also manually adding `-webkit-` in the nested SCSS did not work either.

I have looked at multiple other posts here on the site and could not find a answer that helped me solve this problem. So any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! The background image for the header section was conflicting with the `::before` and `::after`, so I just need to add a higher `z-index` to the heading and it works!

```
.header-block-heading-primary {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;

  &::before {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;

    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    content: "Web Developer";
    z-index: -1;
  }

  &::after {
    content: "Web Developer";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
  }

  &::before {
    color: #ff00c1;
    animation: glitch-effect 3s infinite;
  }

  &::after {
    color: #3498db;
    animation: glitch-effect 2s infinite;
  }

  &:hover::before {
    animation: glitch-effect 1s infinite;
  }

  &:hover::after {
    animation: glitch-effect 2s infinite;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

your animations is working but you need to set `::after` and `::before` `content:"Web Developer"`. you can show the effect in snippet.

```css
.header-block-heading-primary {
  position: relative;
}

.header-block-heading-primary::before,
.header-block-heading-primary::after  {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  content: "Web Developer";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.header-block-heading-primary::before {
  color: red;
  animation: glitch-effect 3s infinite;
}

.header-block-heading-primary::after {
  color: blue;
  animation: glitch-effect 2s infinite;
}
@keyframes glitch-effect {
  0% {
    left: -3px;
    top: -3px;
  }

  25% {
    left: 3px;
    top: 0px;
  }

  50% {
    left: -2px;
    top: 3px;
  }

  75% {
    left: 2px;
    top: -2px;
  }

  100% {
    left: 0px;
    top: -3px;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="header-block-heading-primary">Web Developer</h1>
```

this is the sass code this is working in my page please try this code.

```
.header-block-heading-primary {
  position: relative;
  &::before,
  &::after  {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    content: "Web Developer";
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  &::before {
    color: red;
    animation: glitch-effect 3s infinite;
  }
  &::after {
    color: blue;
    animation: glitch-effect 2s infinite;
  }
}
@keyframes glitch-effect {
  0% {
    left: -3px;
    top: -3px;
  }

  25% {
    left: 3px;
    top: 0px;
  }

  50% {
    left: -2px;
    top: 3px;
  }

  75% {
    left: 2px;
    top: -2px;
  }

  100% {
    left: 0px;
    top: -3px;
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: This is the complied CSS. This works perfectly as per your code snippet, and in a separate test folder I created. However, this does not work in the SCSS code. There is still no glitch effect, even though the compiled CSS now has `content: "Web Developer";` as per your suggestion. This is very confusing. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: @Andrew Shearer please try the code for the SASS i was update it on my answer.

Comment: Hello @KuldipKoradia. So yes your SCSS code works fine too for me on it's own. But when I try to use it in my actual project, it still does not work. I am very confused by this haha. Thanks for helping though! It is very late so I'm going to sleep on it. If it is any help, the surrounding container for this element is also already `positioned: absolute`. Dunno if that would be a contributing factor, don't see how it would.

Comment: it doesn't mean that what is your container position it will work for any text of tag like:<h1 class="header-block-heading-primary">Text Here.</h1>.

Comment: ya one more thing is that your :after and :before content should be the same as the text in <h1>.